# PHP: validate decimal Mysqli data type

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the column data type like this:

```
price decimal(6,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

And my validation code is like this:

```
if ( (!empty($_POST['price'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['price'])) && (isset($_POST['price'])) > 0 ) {
    $price = ($_POST['price']);

} else{
    $price = FALSE;
    echo '<p> Only accept number and must be higher than zero</p>';

}
```

I use the $_POST form for users to submit the value. But you know,

1/ When the user types any non-numeric value such as a,b,c etc, it also validates well.
2/ When the user types the value zero in, it validates well too.

However, the question is that when I tested it with no value typed in. I mean that I left the value empty and hit the 'submit' button, the error message still returned as per the **}else {** part does, but the value was still inserted into the table column with a value of 0.00 technically at the same time.

To my limited knowledge, I can guess that the problem was probably at the Mysqli data type of the table I chose, but i don't know how to correct it.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is to simply move the inserting code to the first `if` statement. That way it'll only insert the value if it is numeric and not empty.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe means that you've failed to stop the insert when $price===false
(i.e. the problem is not the evaluation; it has given you the correct message. You've some programming logic error elsewhere)

Comment: Steve: yes, you got my question now. Do you have any idea to share with me? first time using decimal type. so, I was quite confused!

Comment: as I wrote, it's not the decimal type that is the problem.  The location where you're doing the insert is where the problem lies.